# Powershell: Read a section of a file into a variable

Tags: regex, powershell, batch-file, embedded-resource, polyglot

I'm trying to create a kind of a polyglot script. It's not a true polyglot because it actually requires multiple languages to perform, although it can be "bootstrapped" by either Shell or Batch. I've got this part down no problem.

The part I'm having trouble with is a bit of embedded Powershell code, which needs to be able to load the current file into memory and extract a certain section that is written in yet another language, store it in a variable, and finally pass it into an interpreter. I have an XML-like tagging system that I'm using to mark sections of the file in a way that will hopefully not conflict with any of the other languages. The markers look like this:

```
lang_a_code
# <{LANGB}>
   ... code in language B ...
   ... code in language B ...
   ... code in language B ...
# <{/LANGB}>
lang_c_code
```

The #'s are comment markers, but the comment markers can be different things depending on the language of the section.

The problem I have is that I can't seem to find a way to isolate just that section of the file. I can load the entire file into memory, but I can't get the stuff between the tags out. Here is my current code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command ^

    $re = '(?m)^<{LANGB}^>(.*)^<{/LANGB}^>';^
    $lang_b_code = ([IO.File]::ReadAllText(^'%0^') -replace $re,'$1');^
    echo "${re}";^
    echo "Contents: ${lang_b_code}";
```

Everything I've tried so far results in the entire file being output in the `Contents` rather than just the code between the markers. I've tried different methods of escaping the symbols used in the markers, but it always results in the same thing.

**NOTE**: The use of the `^` is required because the top-level interpreter is Batch, which hangs up on the angle brackets and other random things.

Comment: Did you try `$re = '(?s)<{LANGB}>(.*?)<{/LANGB}>';`?

Comment: That actually returns the entire contents of the file except for the markers themselves. Ie.

    lang_a
    #
    ... language b ...
    #
    lang_c

Comment: Is there several or just one block? If it is just one, you can use the same regex, but with `-match` operator, and then access the text using `$matches[1]` variable that is set as a result of `-match`.

Comment: That answered my question. And FYI, there is only one of that particular block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is just one block, you can use the regex

```
$re = '(?s)^<{LANGB}^>(.*)^^.*^<{/LANGB}^>';^
```

but with `-match` operator, and then access the text using `$matches[1]` variable that is set as a result of `-match`.

So, after the regex declaration, use

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText(^'%0^') -match $re;^
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Yup. Also, I added a ^^.* in there to make sure the beginning of the final line wasn't included either:

`$re = '(?s)^<{LANGB}^>(.*)^^.*^<{/LANGB}^>';^`

Comment: I see, I added that change.